# UART Over IP - How to?

Tags: networking, serial-port

For a student project we have a device with a serial port (UART) wich communicate with a computer by wire. 
As we want to make this system wireless (Device can be far far away from the computer), we had the idea to make the device communicate over IP ;
:
Device Serial port ==> UART/RJ45 converter ? ====> Router ===>Modem

Our question is mainly on the UART RJ45 converter. Does such device exist ? we saw some like this :
http://www.ecnmag.com/product-releases/2008/12/embedded-lan-module-connects-10/100baset-lans

But then how to adress the remote computer ? we would like to copy all traffic from the device and send it back to a specified port on our computer.
We also thought about changing the firmware of the router to OpenWRT to achieve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are several manufacturers of RS-232 to Ethernet (both wired and wireless) converters. Typically these modules establish a TCP/IP socket to emulate a (phone) modem (point-to-point) connection. They accept AT modem commands (on the serial port side) for configuration and specifying an IPv4 address for "dialing out". These have been available for almost 10 years (e.g. [DigiConnect](http://www.digi.com/products/solutions-on-module/digi-connect/)).

Answer (score 3):

... You *could* just get a raspberry Pi, which runs Linux and gives you low level access to a set of IO pins.  Or use an Arduino with the Ethernet module. All of which are readily available and easy to procure. The Arduino and Ethernet modules are for sale at just about every Radio Shack these days.

Unless you have a need to communicate at speeds greater than around 100kbps, the above solutions should work fine.

Edit:

Note that there are Serial libraries available for the Pi:

https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/serial-library/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Wing Tang Wong,
we ll look into it !

Ouassim

Comment: You're only offering the hardware-half of the solution.  There's no software to accomplish the complete task.  That's why one RaspberryPi ($25) costs less than one of these serial-to-Ethernet modules (~$50).

Comment: There is a healthy development community surrounding the Pi. I've updated the answer with a link to the serial library. A quick search results in a good number of Pi and serial interface over network projects.

Depending on the OP's original question, the implementation would depend on the OP's needs.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a good solution thanks to you guys.
I ordered an Rasperry Pi which have IO pins as Wing Tang Wong said, including a set of Rx Tx pin functionning at 3,3v.

Our device work at 5v, so we are going to use a logical converter.

On the RPi we are going to use the ser2net package wich translate a serial input to a TCP/IP network signal ;)

Job done !

Thanks again